# how to bind keyboard shortcut to nsbutton in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to know how to add keyboard shortcuts to buttons for example to press key "R" for pressing  button "Reading" and key "M" for pressing button "meaning" where "Reading" and "meaning" are buttons in window.nib file

Comment: I searched the net but didn't find a code to bind keyboard key to certain button in my nib file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Select the button in the NIB. Select the Attributes inspector. Put focus on the "Key equivalent" field. Type the desired keystroke.

[image]